# Strange DLL Search Order

Tags: windows

What factors can affect the Windows DLL search order for a Desktop Application?

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx), it looks like the "The directory from which the application loaded" should always come first.  Despite this, I am seeing strange behavior on one computer (nowhere else), where First C:\Windows\SysWow64 is being searched, then C:\Windows\, and finally the application directory.  This is breaking the application due to a naming conflict.

[image: Process Monitor capture showing this behavior]

Comment: Check to see if the names of those DLLs being sought are listed as Known DLLs by looking at this registry key on the affected machine:  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\KnownDLLs

Comment: What version of Windows is the errant machine running?  How are the DLLs being pulled in (implicitly linked, calling LoadLibrary from the application)?  Are they mentioned in a manifest?  Do the problematic DLLs have names that match Known DLLs on that machine?

Comment: Does the program attempt to alter the search by calling SetDllDirectory or by trying to enable or disable the safe search list by calling SafeDllSearchMode?  That one, in particular, starts in the system directories and then the "current" directory, which may coincide with the application directory.

Comment: this may be `SafeProcessSearchMode` - look [SearchPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365527(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause is the CWDIllegalInDllSearch setting, [as described in KB2264107.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2264107)

If this is configured, and if the current directory is the same as the application directory, the application directory is left out of the search order.  I'm not sure whether this was the intended behaviour, but it is the behaviour I observed.  (Caveat: that was a couple of years ago, so it might have changed.)

Comment: Apparently, the application directory is in the search order. It just appears later than expected. It is not skipped altogether.

Comment: @IInspectable: yes, that lowers my confidence that this is the OPs specific problem, but I decided that it was still a valid answer to the headline question "What factors can affect the Windows DLL search order".  (Besides, it *might* still be the OPs problem, e.g., if the program explicitly adds the application directory to the search order.)

Comment: think `CWDIllegalInDllSearch` no more used (say in windows 10) this look like `SafeProcessSearchMode` settings.. but this not direct for dll load, but for searchpath

Comment: @RbMm, as far as I know both settings are still available.  They do (slightly) different things after all.